# More elegant scala code

Tags: scala

I am starting to learn scala. Wonder if anyone has a better way to re-write below code in a more functional way. I know there must be one.

```
val buf = ((addr>>24)&0xff) + "." + ((addr>>16)&0xff) + "." + ((addr>>8)&0xff) + "." + ((addr)&0xff)
```

Answer (score 11):

This generates the `Range(24, 16, 8, 0)` with `(24 to 0 by -8)` and then applies the function `addr >> _ & 0xff` to each number using `map`. Lastly, the mapped `Range` of numbers is "joined" with `.` to create a string.

The map is more functional than using the `+` operator but the rest is just syntactic sugar and a library call to `mkString`.

```
val addr = 1024

val buf = (24 to 0 by -8).map(addr >> _ & 0xff).mkString(".")

buf: java.lang.String = 0.0.4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val buf = List(24,16,8,0).map(addr >> _).map(_ & 0xff).mkString(".")
```

Here's how I would do it, similar to Brian's answer but with a short list of values and two simple map() methods using Scala's famous '_' operator. Great question!

Comment: You don't need `_` here: `List(24,16,8,0).map(addr >>).map(0xff &).mkString(".")`

Comment: @KimStebel: Yeah, but then you will get warnings in 2.10 because of postfix operators (rightly in my opinion because they look like Yoda conditions).

Comment: @sschaef: I know and I thank the Scala team for `-language:_`

Answer (score 2):

Some would find the for comprehension a little bit more readable:

```
(for (pos <- 24 to 0 by -8) yield addr >> pos & 0xff) mkString "."
```

Answer (score -2):

The advantage is that input - can be ANY number of integers

```
// trick
implicit class When[F](fun: F) {  
  def when(cond: F => Boolean)(tail: F => F) = if (cond(fun)) tail(fun) else fun
}

// actual one-liner
12345678.toHexString.when(1 to 8 contains _.length % 8)
  (s => "0" * (8 - s.length % 8) + s ).reverse.grouped(2).map
  (Integer.parseInt(_, 16)).toList.reverse.mkString(".")

// 0.203.22.228

// a very big IPv7
BigInt("123456789012345678901").toString(16).when(1 to 8 contains _.length % 8)
  (s => "0" * (8 - s.length % 8) + s ).reverse.grouped(2).map
  (Integer.parseInt(_, 16)).toList.reverse.mkString(".")

// 0.0.0.96.27.228.249.24.242.99.198.83
```

**EDIT**

Explanation because of downvotes. `implicit class When` can be just a library class, it works in `2.10` and allows conditionally execute some of functions in a calls chain. I did not measure performance, and don't care, because an example itself is meant to be an illustration of what is possible, elegant or not.

Comment: You're converting to a string then parsing back again. Then to a string again. Very inefficient.

Comment: This doesn't produce the same behavior (i.e. with leading zeros), so it's probably not what the OP wants, and it doesn't even warn that it doesn't work the same way (bug waiting to happen).

Comment: I knew about leading zeros, but lazily did not correct a bug myself. Thank you so much ^)

Comment: Updated my general solution to IP problem